# Как скопировать файл из контейнера запущенного на удалённом устройстве, с помощью docker api?

Tags: api, docker

docker api 1.41
[https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate\](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate%5C)
На удаленное ПК(линукс) с докером отправляю запросы что бы создать, а потом запустить контейнер(как я понял сразу запустить нельзя).
Контейнер нужен для сборки пакетов линукс в моем случае.
Когда контейнер отрабатывает, у него в файловой системе появляется файл пакета.
Есть ли вариант с выкачать этот файл на ПК с которого я оправляю запросы, типо получить его ответом как-нибудь?
Я не очень шарю, если всё сложно буду рад и ответу без деталей.

Comment: с докер апи не работал, но поиск выдал такое https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerArchive , насколько я понял можно получить tar архив из любой части файловой системы контейнера

Comment: @Exploding Kitten Это реально оно походу, жаль конечно что только в виде архива, но всё роно круто, спасибо!